# Method invocation vs Reflection-Based Event System

Tags: java, events, reflection, methods

Currently, I am trying to create a mod for a application. I've attempted to make it as dynamic as possible, by placing "hooks" inside the application. These hooks will be used to call/create which ever design I choose (event system/ method invocation). I wish to know which one would be better for my project. If you have any other ways of doing this that are "better", please let me know.

If I do method invocation, I'll call a method inside the super class (this super class is for the mods and the mods extend it). The mod if using the method being called.. will run the code inside.

If I do a reflection-based event system. I'll create an object (the creation of the object will be caused by the hooks), and the mod (subclass) will listen for the creation of this object... I.E

```
getEventManager().registerlistener(this)

@EventHandler
public void onCertainEvent(EventTick event){}
```

Which one would be better in terms of "good" code and efficiency? Or if you have another way of doing it.. please let me know.

Comment: Neither. The best option is to have an `interface` that mods can implement. Reflection is relatively expensive and should only be used when you don't know types and method signatures at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using annotations is one style of writing the code.  This can help removing lots of boiler plate code.  While reflections is slower and more cumbersome to write for the caller, it can be nicer for the callee.  By slower, it is typically 30-100 nano-seconds once the code has warmed up which might not be important to you .

I suggest you follow the approach which appears to be the most natural way to describe your problem.  What is simpler and easier to understand is usually the most important.